# Tips need with time difference function or using Reduce in R

Tags: r, function, time

I need to write a function that calculates the time difference between subsequent timestamps and the first time-stamp each time. In the dataset there are about ~80,000 timestamps. I had written the following function:

```
timeDIFF <- function(data){
  t_diff <- rep(0,length = nrow(data))
  for (i in 2:nrow(data)){
    t_diff[i] <- as.numeric(difftime(data["TimeStamp"][i,],
                                     data["TimeStamp"][1,],
                                     units="hours"))
  }
  return(t_diff)
}
```

*General tips on improving the elegance are welcome by the way!*

It doesn't take that long to run, but considering I will be receiving a lot more observations the time will significantly increase. Then I came across the `Reduce()` function and wrote something like this:

```
x <- strptime(date$TimeStamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
f <- function(a,b) as.numeric(difftime(b,a,units="hours"))
t_diff <- Reduce(f,x)
```

First of all, it doesn't do exactly what I want since it would theoretically take the difference between subsequent timestamps and not only with the first timestamp. That can be solved too I assume -- just not sure how quite yet. However, more importantly, I get the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time1) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

When I provide the `origin`, I get the following error:

```
Error in difftime(b, a, units = "hours", origin = "1970-01-01") : 
  unused argument (origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Any suggestions? Perhaps using `Reduce` or improving the elegance of my own function. 

--Cheers, tstev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of vectorization:

```
times <- as.POSIXct("2015-02-05 12", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz = "GMT") + (0:3) * 3600
#[1] "2015-02-05 12:00:00 GMT" "2015-02-05 13:00:00 GMT" "2015-02-05 14:00:00 GMT" "2015-02-05 15:00:00 GMT"

as.numeric(difftime(times[-1], times[1], units="hours"))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

I'm not sure why you think you should use `Reduce` for this.

Comment: Wow thanks mate! I was looking at ways at improving code and `Reduce` came up. In any case. Thanks a lot!